# How to add a bottom curve in TabView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, curve, tabview, tabitem

I just want a Bottom curve in center of my tabView but i am not able to access tabView shape property.

[image: Final Image]

This is what i want.

Note:

> The curve should always remain in center. And the items should swap, which is already achieved in the given code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DashboardTabBarView: View {

@State private var selection: String = "home"

struct Item {
    let title: String
    let color: Color
    let icon: String
}

@State var items = [
    Item(title: "cart", color: .red, icon: "cart"),
    Item(title: "home", color: .blue, icon: "house"),
    Item(title: "car", color: .green, icon: "car"),
]

var body: some View {

    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(items, id: \.title) { item in // << dynamically !!
            item.color
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: item.icon)
                    Text(item.title)
                }
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: selection) { title in // << reorder with centered item
        let target = 1
        if var i = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.title == title }) {
            if i > target {
                i += 1
            }
            items.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: target), toOffset: i)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you have to make your own custom TabView to create that. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72163737/can-not-get-correct-position-of-view-in-swiftui/72165363#72165363

Comment: You have to make your own, there is no way of altering `TabView` to do it. This question has been asked many times on SO with different response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, actually we need to solve two problems here, first - find a height of tab bar, and second - correctly align view custom view with represented selected item over standard tab bar. Everything else is *mechanics*.

Here is simplified demo. Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16.

[image: demo]

Main part:

- a possible solution for problem #1

```
struct TabContent<V: View>: View {
    @Binding var height: CGFloat
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> V

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in  // << read bottom edge !!
            content()
                .onAppear {
                    height = gp.safeAreaInsets.bottom
                }
                .onChange(of: gp.size) { _ in
                    height = gp.safeAreaInsets.bottom
                }
        }
    }
}
```

- a possible solution for problem #2

```
    // Just put customisation in z-ordered over TabView
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            // .. content here
        }

        TabSelection(height: tbHeight, item: selected)
    }


struct TabSelection: View {
    let height: CGFloat
    let item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Curve()    // put curve over tab bar !!
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: height)
                .foregroundColor(item.color)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()   // << push to bottom !!
        .overlay(
            // Draw overlay
            Circle().foregroundColor(.black)
                .frame(height: height).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .shadow(radius: 4)
                .overlay(Image(systemName: item.icon)
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white))
            , alignment: .bottom)
    }
}
```

[Test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestReorderTabItemsPerSelection.swift)

Comment: Hello @Asperi how to add shadow like attached images in the question? 
As your answer content item has different color so we can see the tabView perfectly. But if the item background color is white we cannot see tabView separator as this problem I want to add shadow to tabView along with the curve. Thanks.